# How do i write in Excel file the value of individual popup and each popup contains the table

Tags: java, excel

The below code executes on 21 rows and, when clicking on each row, a popup appears which contains a table that I need to write to an Excel file.

Row 0, 1,2 and 3 are just printing the name of page and other headings.

From the row 5th it should print each table of each popup(21 popups value).

Following code writing only last measure and also printing only the last row of that particular table(popup). I don't know to increment the rows for next popup/table to write on excel also need to increase the number of rows for a  inner loop `for(int j=0;j<totalNoOfLOB.size();j++)` to print all values.

And `int totalNoOfPopupRows =totalNoOfRows+1;` gives me the total number of rows for each popup. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 public void measureDetail() throws Exception {

     Actions act = new Actions(driver);

     clickOnAllMeasureListOneAfterOther.forEach(s - > {

             try {
                 Thread.sleep(3000);
                 s.click();

                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\pdholakia\\Desktop\\N4.xls");
                 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
                 XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("PCP_Performance");
                 sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(moduleName.getText());

                 sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue(pageName.getText());

                 sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellValue(hierarchy.getText());
                 sheet.createRow(2).createCell(1).setCellValue(hierarchyOption.getText());

                 sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue(program.getText());
                 sheet.createRow(3).createCell(1).setCellValue(programOption.getText());


                 int totalNoOfRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='divMeasureDetails']/table/tbody/trxpathExpression")).size();
                 int totalNoOfPopupRows = totalNoOfRows + 1;
                 //totalNoOfPopupRows is giving me the size of every popup, the number of rows of popup are dynamic.

                 int row = 5;
                 String measureName1 = measureName.getText();
                 System.out.println("*********************************************************************************************");
                 System.out.println("MEASURE NAME::::-" + measureName1);
                 sheet.createRow(row).createCell(0).setCellValue(measureName1);

                 ///////Code for Row 1 of pupup/////////         
                 String com = combinedText.getText();
                 System.out.format("%8s", com);
                 sheet.createRow(row + 1).createCell(0).setCellValue(com);

                 for (int cRow = 0; cRow < combinedRowValues.size(); cRow++) {
                     String combinedRowValue = combinedRowValues.get(cRow).getText();
                     System.out.format("%10s", combinedRowValue);
                     sheet.getRow(row + 1).createCell(cRow + 1).setCellValue(combinedRowValue);
                 }

                 String numeratorDenominatorValue = numeratorDenominator.getText();
                 System.out.format("%20s", numeratorDenominatorValue);
                 sheet.getRow(row + 1).createCell(4).setCellValue(numeratorDenominatorValue);

                 /////// Code for Row 2 of pupup/////////    

                 System.out.println("\n");
                 System.out.println("Business Line(LOB) |  Performance | Minimum_Threshold | Actual Values | To Target   ");
                 sheet.createRow(row + 2).createCell(0).setCellValue("Business Line");
                 sheet.getRow(row + 2).createCell(1).setCellValue("Performance");
                 sheet.getRow(row + 2).createCell(2).setCellValue("Minimum_Threshold");
                 sheet.getRow(row + 2).createCell(3).setCellValue("Actual Values");
                 sheet.getRow(row + 2).createCell(4).setCellValue("To Target");

                 ////// Code for Row 3/4/5. of popup ///////
                 for (int j = 0; j < totalNoOfLOB.size(); j++)(totlNoOfLob can be 1 / 2 / 3 or 4) {

                     System.out.format("%15s", totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());
                     sheet.createRow(row + 3).createCell(0).setCellValue(totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());

                     System.out.format("%15s", combinedPerformanceOfMeasure.get(j + 3).getText());
                     sheet.getRow(row + 3).createCell(1).setCellValue(totalNoOfLOB.get(j).getText());

                     System.out.format("%15s", thresdhholdsLowerValues.get(j).getText());
                     sheet.getRow(row + 3).createCell(2).setCellValue(thresdhholdsLowerValues.get(j).getText());


                     System.out.format("%25s", listOfActualValues.get(j + 1).getText());
                     sheet.getRow(row + 3).createCell(3).setCellValue(listOfActualValues.get(j + 1).getText());


                     System.out.format("%15s", listOfToTarget.get(j).getText());

                     sheet.getRow(row + 3).createCell(4).setCellValue(listOfActualValues.get(j + 1).getText());
                     System.out.println("\n");
                 }
                 try {
                     fos.flush();
                     wb.write(fos);
                     fos.close();


                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 act.moveToElement(labelProgram).click().build().perform();
             });

     }
 }
```

Comment: Really hard to solve this question without any HTML or context of the page you are trying to automate here. If you could provide the HTML of your page or link to your page, that will help solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry i can't just need a help how do i increase the loop once its has written in excel 6 lines say for example now wanted to write 5 rows of next popup then wanted to write it down 4 lines of next popup. My code is over writing only showing the last popup/table values/rows.

Comment: I am re-classifying this question as excel, and not Selenium, because the issue is inherently related to Excel.

Comment: I am trying to fetch value from console to excel using apache POI, using TestNG framework, Selenium.